# configure rupture for webpack in angular 4

Tags: angular, webpack, stylus

I am new to web packs. For my style sheet compilation i use stylus. One good feature of using stylus is we can use ruptures to generate media queries. How do we configure rupture npm package with web pack in angular 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add rupture as a dev dependency with `yarn add rupture -D` or `npm install rupture -D`

Add **stylePreprocessorOptions** to **.angular-cli.json** file in the root directory

```json
"styles": [
  "styles.styl"
],
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
  "../node_modules/rupture/"
  ]
},
```

rupture is now available to be imported across the app using **@import "rupture"**

Placing the `@import "rupture"` statement in the global **styles.styl** file, makes it globally available without individual imports in multiple files

**Note:** `styles` in the code block is just a reference to the location, add `stylePreprocessorOptions` where ever you want but it has be a part of an object in **apps** array